# How to bound this integral with the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, potential-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and consider the following situation.
$$\phi(x) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^d} f(y) d\sigma(y)$$
Where $\partial \Omega$ denotes the boundary of $\Omega$ and $\sigma$ denotes the surface measure. I want to show that the nontangential maximal function of $\phi$ is bounded on $L^p(\partial \Omega)$ when $f \in L^p(\partial \Omega)$ for $1 < p < \infty$. To do so we look at the definition of the nontangential maximal function (denoted by $(\phi)^{*})$. Let $P \in \partial \Omega$ denote a point on the boundary. Then
$$ (\phi)^*(P) = \sup_{\substack{x \in \Omega \\ |x-P| < C_1 \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)}} \left| \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^d} f(y) d\sigma(y) \right|$$
I have split the integral in multiple parts and managed to bound some of them by the maximal function of $f$ in $P$. However I'm missing one part.

> I want to show that
>   $$ \sup_{\substack{x \in \Omega \\ |x-P| < C_1\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)}} \left| \int_{|P-y| > 2|P-x|} \frac{|P-y|}{|P-y|^d} f(y) d\sigma(y) \right|  \leq C_2 \mathcal{M}_{\partial \Omega}(f)(P)$$
>   With the maximal function defined as
>   $$\mathcal{M}_{\partial \Omega}(f)(P) = \sup_{(B\cap \partial \Omega) \ni P}\frac{1}{\sigma\{B\cap \partial \Omega\}}\int_{B \cap \partial \Omega} |f(y)| d\sigma(y)$$

Comment: are those the same $C$? What is $C$?

Comment: @mathworker21 I have labelled the constants $C_1$ and $C_2$. $C_1$ is a constant that basically defines a cone from which $x \in \Omega$ can be chosen (hence it is the non-tangential maximal function). $C_2$ is a positive constant.

Comment: What are the quantifiers? For all $C_1$, there is $C_2$?